# How to mark a object for deletion in x days time?

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I have a regional object store. I would like to be able to tell a particular object that I want you deleted in 5 days time from now.

How do you suggest I implement?

I don't really want to keep track of the object in a database, and based on time send delete commands as a separate process. Is there any tag that could be set to get deletion to occur at a later time (from now, not a specific time in the past)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no functionality built into Google Cloud Storage to do this.
You can configure [Lifecycle Management](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/lifecycle) to delete objects according to a number of criteria (including age) - but deleting at a particular date in the future isn't one of the supported conditions and in fact there's no guarantee that a lifecycle condition will run the same day the condition becomes true. Instead you would have to implement this functionality yourself (e.g., in a Compute Engine or App Engine implementation).

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I'm trying out lifecycle management, with "Event based holds by default" enabled. The delete idea will change to remove "events based hold" flag, and then it should delete after that. It's clumsy, but hopefully is good enough.